# Write access on Apache WebDAV server

Tags: apache-2.4, mount, webdav, arch-linux, write

I have set up a WebDAV server running Arch Linux 3.19.3 and Apache 2.4, according to the Arch Wiki [[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server)] [[2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WebDAV)] and the Apache Documentation [[3](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dav.html)].

The **only** changes I made to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so

DAVLockDB /home/httpd/dav/DAVLock

Alias /dav "/srv/http/dav"
<Directory "/srv/http/dav">
    DAV On
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName name
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/passwd
    Require user name
    Order allow,deny
    allow 
</Directory>
```

Related folders and their owners and permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x root root /srv
drwxrwxr-x http http /srv/http
drwxrwxr-x http http /srv/http/dav
```

As I’m editing this I realize the following is where the problem is.

```
drw-rw-r-x http http /home/httpd
```

The permissions should in stead be

```
drwxrwxr-x http http /home/httpd
```

since you can’t access the contents of a folder without being able to execute (open) it.

I’m leaving the thread for the afterlife. Hopefully someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is where the problem is.

```
drw-rw-r-x http http /home/httpd
```

The permissions should in stead be (and the same for the subdirectory)

```
drwxrwxr-x http http /home/httpd
```

since you can’t access the contents of a folder without being able to execute (open) it.